# How to get web driver urls from spark master page (JSON) via REST API

Tags: apache-spark

I've my Spark UI running at http://server:8080/ from which I could see lot of information, but in particular the running application.
In particular the column name will report the name and the URL for the web driver. I figured out that I could get the (more or less) same information into JSON format using the following: http://server:8080/json.
That is working fine BUT in the application list I do NOT get the web driver information as you could see into below snipset.

```
"activeapps" : [ {
    "id" : "app-20200529134214-2543",
    "starttime" : 1590759734237,
    "name" : "REDACTED",
    "cores" : 4,
    "user" : "REDACTED",
    "memoryperslave" : 6144,
    "submitdate" : "Fri May 29 13:42:14 UTC 2020",
    "state" : "RUNNING",
    "duration" : 496967952
```

There's a way to get this information, from this REST or another API. The only restriction is that is has to be REST.

Thank you

Comment: Nope, I know that API. I precisely need to get the information out of that but in order to do that I need the web driver port (that is dynamically assigned) and the only place where I saw them listed together is into above mentioned UI